# Opel Astra hatchback is taking too much water and the water bottle is boiling in a short time drive or I should add water while its runing

Tags: cooling-system

My car its Opel Astra hatchback.

It is taking too much water and the water bottle is boiling after a short distance.

What I'm suppose to do?

Comment: Do you see coolant leaking?  If so, where from?

Comment: No leak sir the only thing I saw is there is a pipe that brings water from radiator back to the bottle I don't know if that how it works

Comment: Someone said i must start the engine and give it time to hydling before drive

Answer (score 1):

There are a few of possibilities -

- The coolant is boiling due to a lack of coolant circulation
- The bubbling is exhaust gas due to a faulty cylinder head gasket
- The expansion tank cap is not holding the correct pressure

A mechanic should be able to use an exhaust gas analyser to detect exhaust gasses in the expansion tank.  This will tell you if it is the cylinder head gasket at fault.

If it happens very quickly while the engine is cold, I would also suspect the gasket has failed.

If the temperature gauge shows a high temperature, then maybe it could be a coolant problem.  This could be due to a broken drive belt, a faulty water pump, faulty thermostat or blocked pipe/radiator.

If the expansion tank cap is faulty, the cooling system may not be reaching normal pressure which allows the coolant to boil at a lower temperature, so this is a possibility, too.

Unless you are able to check these things yourself, you are best just taking it to a mechanic.  The issue will only get worse if you leave it and could end up with a seized engine.

How quickly does it happen when driving with a cold engine?

Does it happen mainly when driving slowly or driving quickly?

Comment: I drive about 15kilometres to my workplace but today I had to put water twice

Comment: Or simply a bad leak.

Comment: I had a leak in a certain speed range , no leak when stopped, no leak at moderate speed. the water pump only leaked at highway speed.

Comment: @blacksmith37 A bad leak is a possibility, but leaks don’t usually cause boiling in the expansion tank.

Comment: "you are best just taking it to a mechanic" This. The OP doesn't sound like someone who works on cars, and ignoring the problem could get very expensive very quickly.

Comment: A leak will mean the system cannot pressurize, so allowing "boiling"...

Comment: I'm sure there is a leak let me just take it to mechanic thank you all for your help you are the best god bless

Comment: @SehGarlic Report back with the mechanic's findings.